# Send a notification to user when database is updated Azure Notification Hub

Tags: c#, database, azure, notifications

Let me explain my problem :
I have a MySQL database (That I launch with WAMP) where I store all my data and a UWP Client application.

I would like to send a notification to the client when my database is updated so the app can reload the data stored inside it's variables.

I've seen some solutions, but i wanted to try to use the Azure Notification Hub to do this project. I created a Notification Hub and an app in the Windows Notification Service.

I successfully sent a notification to myself using the app, but now I would like that the process of sending the notification to be automatic when a trigger in the database is called.

I saw a plugin named SYS-UDF that can lauch commands from SQL using functions like "sys_eval" or "sys_exec".

So i created a console app that I think was able to send a simple push notification. But I encountered a problem : I can't use a console app to launch a push notification, that is because it is not published in the WNS and it can't be published, because it's a console application.

So I'm stuck, here. Is there any other ways to send a notification to Azure Notification Service ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: This seems like a separation of concerns problem. Databases just hold data, it seems likely you want to do this where ever it is that is updating the database

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for your answer, I didn't see it that way, it makes more sense. Ha ve a good day